# Jquery UI Draggable items appearing in one row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, web-applications

I have a simple draggable function here that I am using for a math game I am trying to get my numbers to appear in one row but currently with this code below they appear stacked on top of each other like this
1
2
3
4
How do i get them to be like this 1 2 3 4 5

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>


    <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

      <script>


       $(function() {
            $( "#draggable1" ).draggable();
          });
          </script>
        </head>
         <body>
    <div id="draggable1" class="ui-widget-content">
      <p><img src="mypicturesurl.com is here;"></p>
          </div>
<div id="draggable1" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p><img src="mypictureurl.com;"></p>
</div>
<div id="draggable1" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p><img src="Samepictureurl.com;"></p>
</div>
         </body>
```

i am just testing all with the one function to see if i can get them into the row or not. Thank you for help

Comment: Could you include a screenshot showing what you are currently looking at?

Comment: Just my image one by one on the left part of the screen like this                      1     all the way down

Comment: I'm unclear as to what what the issue is you are experiencing. Could you try rewording your question?

Comment: i will post screen shots

Comment: Id's are always unique. Please change your `draggable1` id to class first.

Comment: http://s9.postimg.org/8ebny41dr/exampleszz.png    what i dont want is the images going vertically i want them to be horizontal and each one draggable

Comment: You want to include the display property in your CSS:  .draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; display: inline;}

Comment: <style>
  #draggable1 { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; display: inline;}
  </style>
<style>
  #draggable2 { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; display: inline; }
  </style>    is not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're going to want to make sure you add `float: left` to your CSS to make sure the elements start on the left side and remain horizontal. You must also make sure that you inherit this class with each element. Your code used the `draggable` ID, which none of your elements inherited. Additionally, element IDs should be different, so I made each element have a unique ID in the amended code below as well as changing the CSS type to a class:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    <style>
        .draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#draggable1" ).draggable();
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="draggable1" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
            <p><img src="mypicturesurl.com is here;"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="draggable2" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
            <p><img src="mypictureurl.com;"></p>
        </div>
        <div id="draggable3" class="draggable ui-widget-content">
            <p><img src="Samepictureurl.com;"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left;` to make it horizontal.

```
.draggable1 img { 
       width: 150px; 
       height: 150px; 
       padding: 0.5em;
       float: left;
  }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/znu6brgu/)

Comment: is the . the same as # in #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }

Comment: I have added working fiddle, you can check the rest of the code there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have multiple elements with the same ID `draggable1` in your HTML. Javascript will fail to recognize all of them. If you need to select multiple elements consider using a class selector instead, which will allow you to select all of them at once. Then your javascript will change to:

```
$(function() {
  $( ".draggable1" ).draggable();
});
```

and you will be able to drag all of your elements.

Next, your CSS is set to affect elements with ID: `draggable` (there are none). Instead, you should use the same class selector before (since there are multiple), and this will change to:

```
.draggable1 { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
```

Finally, if you need them to start side by side, instead of stacked on top of each other, consider floating them left: `float: left`.

Also you should try to separate your HTML, CSS, and Javascript into separate files to keep the logic distinct as your application grows. This is considered good style.